# Support for a chart choice & JQchart maximum visualization optimization

Tags: charts, highcharts, jqchart

I have a big project that requires charting and I need to make a decision between these two charting choices:

JQchart - Looks most dynamic and easy to use with MVC support, The problem is that it looks inferior to Highcharts in data visualization.

Highcharts - The DotNet support is depndable on a 3rd part api library, It might not be as dynamic as JQcharts but it looks significantly better than it.

I need some guidance if it's possible to add some "magic" to the JQchart lib to look better(I know Trirand plugin it's not enough), Any examples with optimized visualization  will be wellcome, Any suggestions for some other plugins are welcome as well.

Comment: Upon examining Trirand...it looks EXACTLY like HighCharts as far as I can tell: http://www.trirand.net/demochartaspnet.aspx What visualizations do you think aren't up to par with HighCharts?

Comment: Implenting visual theming like in Highcharts:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut/grid

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I don't know jqChart very well, so I can't offer any recommendations on the ability to actually theme it like HighCharts.